# File read problems in C

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, printf

I'm having some random glitches occur when reading and writing to a file in C. Typically, the algorithms work correctly, but occasionally I'll get a hiccup to where the loop I'm using stops working.

The file I'm using, after reading and writing from it, says [Incomplete last line] 1 line, 2 characters when I VI it, but this is what it looks like when it's working. I'm keeping track of a value in the file and counting down with it every time the function executes. However, when the loops freeze up, I VI the file and it reads 1 line, 3 characters, with no mention of an incomplete last line. It would make sense for the file to not be read with the line incomplete, but this is the only case in which it actually works.

I can normally fix this by deleting the file, and letting the program recreate it, but this is meant to be in a monitoring application so I need to squash the glitch completely. I'm using fprintf, and fgets to read and write from the file, and to my knowledge they are supposed to terminate the file correctly, or am I wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks, all.

I'm enclosing the code I've written for the whole algorithm below:

```
   if loop executes -> 
       {
          /*Set countdown timer for outage, only email after down for 24 hours. */


         if( access( filePath, F_OK ) != -1 ) /* If file does not exist */
         {
           /* Does exist so do nothing */ 
         } 
         else
         {
           if ( ( fileFd = fopen( filePath, "w" ) ) != 0 )
           {
             /* Generates file */
           }

            fclose(fileFd);

           if ( ( fileFd = fopen( filePath, "r+" ) ) != 0 )
           {
             fprintf(fileFd, "%d", bridgeTimer_limit); /* Reset timer to default countdown */
             rewind(fileFd);
             fgets(bridgeOneTimeLeft, 10, fileFd);
             bridgeOneDownCount = atoi(bridgeOneTimeLeft);
           }

         }

         fclose(fileFd);

         if ( ( fileFd = fopen( filePath, "r+" ) ) != 0 )
          { 
            fgets(bridgeOneTimeLeft, 10, fileFd);
            rewind(fileFd);

            bridgeOneDownCount = atoi(bridgeOneTimeLeft);

            if (bridgeOneDownCount > 0) /* Timer still counting down */
            {
              /* Continue timer countdown, decrementing 15 minutes per count */
              bridgeOneDownCount = bridgeOneDownCount - 1;
              fprintf(fileFd, "%d" , bridgeOneDownCount);
              rewind(fileFd);
              pinfo(("bridgeOneDownCount counting down == %d", bridgeOneDownCount));
            }               
            else if (bridgeOneDownCount - 1 <= 0) /* Time reaches 0 */
            {
              sprintf(cmd2,"`which send_alert_email` \'%s\' ", reasonText);
              system(cmd2);
            }
            fclose(fileFd);
          }
       }
   }
   else
   {
     if ( ( fileFd = fopen( filePath, "r+" ) ) != 0 )
     {
       fprintf(fileFd, "%d", bridgeTimer_limit); /* Reset timer to default countdown */
       rewind(fileFd);
       fgets(bridgeOneTimeLeft, 10, fileFd);
       bridgeOneDownCount = atoi(bridgeOneTimeLeft);
     }
     fclose(fileFd);
     return;
   }
```

Comment: if the contents of the file are wong, then i'd be looking at the code that here just says `/* Generates file */`

Comment: fclose() belongs INTO the if (fopen()) {...here...}

Comment: What do you mean "freeze up"? Does the program stop at one particularly line (debugger!)? If so, what line? Or do you get into an infinite loop?

Comment: Note that there's no newline or a flush after `fprintf`, so I'm not sure if that integer gets written properly every time.

Comment: @PeterMiehle - Is there a way to manually insert a carriage return into the file?

Comment: @Evert - This is part of a larger enterprise-scale application so unfortunately I can't run a debugger, and the build process is somewhat clunky, so testing is difficult. The loop just doesn't seem to execute by this point. It's connected to a java client that acts as a GUI for the error outputs, but it just displays a generic error, so it seems to be sending back bad values somewhere, just not sure where....

Comment: If your `if( access( filePath, F_OK ) != -1 )` is not true, code performs a `fclose(fileFd);`, but the value of `fileFd` it not determined.  @Peter Miehle mentioned trouble with `fclose()` too.  Recommend review of placements of the various `fclose()` statements.

Comment: The `fclose()` issue is real, but I would expect the application to crash hard (eg, segfault) if you're trying to close a file with an undefined filepointer. It does depend on the OS how it crashes, but it doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: @NickL. Have you tried to simply recreate the problem, by turning the above code with some additions into a standalone executable, and then running that hundreds of times? Just see if it crashes/freezes then as well.

Comment: Also, since you mention a java client: does that access the file at the same time? With all the `rewind()`s, that may be causing problems.

Comment: The logic depends on a series of value inputs so replicating the logic in a stand-alone app would be difficult. One of the joys of enterprise-level development, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to explain the error from you code. Please check the issue that there may be some path in condition where it is not closes. But this program need not to open and close several times. You can open once and close lastly. If you need to abort rest of the operation in loop use `continue` keyword after 'fclose(fileFd)'. Or finally after loop you can use

```
if(fileFd != NULL)
    fclose(fileFd);
```

Comment: My reason for invoking so many fopens is, I need to change the permissions on it as the algorithm continues. Say, I need it to be "W", at first, then R+ later on. Can I just change those as I go along, without having to close and open the file?

Comment: `r+` Opens the file for both reading and writing. (The file must exist.) `w+` Opens the file as an empty file for both reading and writing. If the file exists, its contents are destroyed.
`a+` Opens the file for reading and appending; the appending operation includes the removal of the EOF marker before new data is written to the file and the EOF marker is restored after writing is complete; creates the file first if it doesn't exist. I think you need only `W+`

Comment: I need to read the file first though, and get a value from it before I write to it again later....if I use W+ then that value gets destroyed before I can retrieve it. I want to have a piece of code in there that will create the file if it gets deleted, though....otherwise W+ would be perfect.